# using phonegap-facebook-plugin iOS crash

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Finaly i need to ask this question here, because i already spent more then 3 days to solve this problem. i failed to find any solution for my issue.
I'm using
xcode : 5.1.1
Cordova : 3.4
iOS : 7.1

I'm using sample code from the phonegap-facebook-plugin. When i run my app first time and i logged in successfully but when i run my app second time it goes crash. Crashing is happens only if i restart my app without log out.

Crash at line :

`[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.loginCallbackId];`

in  method
`- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{`

and the Xcode Log is :

`FBLogin[4063:60b] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument`

Comment: where you get the plugin? url?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin i get it from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)